how to perform the onclick method through event listener js
I have a function toggleVariantList which is responsible for displaying a dropdown. Is it possible to make the toggleVariantList method fire through the event listener without using onClick?
Dropdown code PHP Laravel:
<div class="variant-checker__button" onclick="toggleVariantList(this)">
    <div class="default-item-wrap">
      <span class="default-item">
         {{ $Product->variants->where('stock_status', 1)->first()->attribute_values[0]->varchar ?? $Product->attribute('volume')->first()->valuesToHuman() }}
      </span>
      <svg class="ic icon-arrow-down">
           <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-down"></use>
       </svg>
       </div>
  </div>

  <div class="variant-checker-buttons-list">
  @foreach($Product->variants as $variant)
     @if($variant->image && $variant->stock_status === 1)
      <button class="list-item button-item" onclick="changeVariant(this)" data-value="{{ $variant->id }}" product-name="{{ $variant->title }}" data-price="{{ $variant->price }}" data-image="http://onelove.ua/storage/{{ $variant->image->path }}">
        {{ $variant->attribute_values[0]->varchar }}
      </button>
    @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
@push('script')
<script>
        
    function toggleVariantList(button) {
        var $container = $(button).closest('.variant-checker');
        $container.find('.variant-checker-buttons-list').toggleClass('active');
    }
</script>
@endpush


"make the toggleVariantList method fire through the event listener without using onClick" - can you please clarify, what that is supposed to mean? You can trigger events via script, to get the associated handlers executed, but I can't tell if that is actually what you mean here, based on this rather weird phrasing.

Yes, I need to trigger the event through a script. I tried this $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).ready()
function toggleVariantList(button) {
var $container = $(button).closest('.variant-checker');
$container.find('.variant-checker-buttons-list').toggleClass('active');
}
$('.variant-checker__button').on('click', function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.variant-checker');
    toggleVariantList($container);
});

});

That is hard to read in comments. Please edit your question, and add the code in there, properly formatted.

`(document).ready(function() {
$('.variant-checker__button').on('click', function() {
var $container = $(this).closest('.variant-checker');
toggleVariantList($container);
});
});
function toggleVariantList(button) {
    var $container = $(button).closest('.variant-checker');
    $container.find('.variant-checker-buttons-list').toggleClass('active');
}`


jQuery explicitly provides https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ for this.

So basically to trigger the toggleVariantList function using an event listener instead of using onclick, you can remove the inline onclick attribute and add an event listener to the button element in JavaScript.
1. HTML Laravel code
<div class="variant-checker__button">
    <div class="default-item-wrap">
        <span class="default-item">
            {{ $Product->variants->where('stock_status', 1)->first()->attribute_values[0]->varchar ?? $Product->attribute('volume')->first()->valuesToHuman() }}
        </span>
        <svg class="ic icon-arrow-down">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-down"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="variant-checker-buttons-list">
    @foreach($Product->variants as $variant)
        @if($variant->image && $variant->stock_status === 1)
            <button class="list-item button-item" data-value="{{ $variant->id }}" product-name="{{ $variant->title }}" data-price="{{ $variant->price }}" data-image="http://onelove.ua/storage/{{ $variant->image->path }}">
                {{ $variant->attribute_values[0]->varchar }}
            </button>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>

2. JavaScript code
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var button = document.querySelector('.variant-checker__button');
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            toggleVariantList(this);
        });
    });

    function toggleVariantList(button) {
        var container = button.closest('.variant-checker');
        container.querySelector('.variant-checker-buttons-list').classList.toggle('active');
    }
</script>

